# Authorization Error at Event Kit. [Command Line Tool]

Tags: swift, macos, eventkit

I have created MacOS Command Line Application. However, I have got the error below when trying to access EKEventStore.

> CoreData: XPC: Unable to load metadata: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134070 "An error occurred in the
>   persistent store." UserInfo={Problem=request failed, insufficient
>   permission}

In Mac Os Sierra this works well . But when upgraded to Mojave , it gave me that error.

**main.swift :**

```swift
import Foundation
import EventKit

let store = EKEventStore()

print("asdasd")
```

**info.plist:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>Privacy – Calendars Usage Description</key>
        <string>You have to give permission to access your calendar sources</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Application runs from compiled command line file. However , it does not enable debugging. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer elsewhere for this?

Comment: I have this issue too. I think the issue is that LLDB doesn't have permissions to create the persistent store at `~/Library/Calendars/Calendar Cache`.

Answer (score 1):

I see this behavior on Catalina, too. 
The only workaround was to use a deprecated objc call:

`store = [[EKEventStore alloc] initWithAccessToEntityTypes:EKEntityMaskReminder];`

I do nothing with the result, but on the first call a pop-up asks for permissions of >terminal< to access the reminders. Then it works.

I've written a tool to export reminders, which uses this:
[Tool to Export Reminders](https://mitt-woch.de/index.php/software/6-remliex)

Comment: This didn't work for me; I got the same error even though I used that deprecated call in Objective-C.

Comment: Did you try the source from the tool I wrote, which worked for me? (Just as a try.)
Did you set the access-flag in your project, which grants for the desired resource?

Comment: I just tried your tool and I still got the same 'request failed, insufficient permission' output when I ran it in XCode.

Comment: Did you set the Flag at Mac->Systemsettings->Security->Privacy->Reminders->Allow Terminal access to Reminders? This counts, if you run the tool from Terminal.

Comment: I have no issues with calendar events/reminders when running programs in the terminal, either using `EKEventStore()` or the deprecated Objective-C code. My issue is that it doesn't work when running it inside XCode or when using LLDB. I have allowed XCode to access my calendar and reminders in my system preferences.

Comment: Thats correct, same for me: You may run the program from terminal etc., but starting from xcode causes the excpetion. Maybe you mock some data for debugging instead of a direct access? Sorry for that.